# Peak Filter has clicks and pops

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, signal-processing, core-audio

```
OSStatus MusicPlayerCallback ( 
                       void *                     inRefCon, 
                       AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *   ioActionFlags, 
                       const AudioTimeStamp *         inTimeStamp, 
                       UInt32                     inBusNumber, 
                       UInt32                     inNumberFrames, 
                       AudioBufferList *            ioData) { 


MusicPlaybackState *musicPlaybackState = (MusicPlaybackState*) inRefCon; 

double sampleinp; 

double A,omega,sn,cs,alpha,Bandwidth; 

double dbGain; 

double   a0,a1,a2,b0,b1,b2; 

dbGain = 1.0; 

A=pow(10.0,dbGain/40.0); 

Bandwidth = 2.0; 

omega=2 * M_PI * 800.0/44100.0; 

sn=sin(omega); 

cs=cos(omega); 

alpha=sn*sinh(((M_LN2/2)*Bandwidth*omega)/sn); 


//Peak Filter Biquad 

b0 =1.0 + alpha * A; 

b1 = (-2.0 * cs); 

b2 = 1.0 - alpha * A; 

a0 = 1.0 + (alpha /A); 

a1 = -2.0 * cs; 

a2 = 1.0 - (alpha /A); 



double b0a0, b1a0, b2a0, a1a0, a2a0; 

double static x1; 

double static x2; 

double static y1; 

double static y2; 


b0a0=b0/a0;   

b1a0=b1/a0; 

b2a0=b2/a0; 

a1a0=a1/a0; 

a2a0=a2/a0; 


for (int i = 0 ; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++){ 


  AudioBuffer buffer = ioData->mBuffers[i]; 
  AudioSampleType *outSample = buffer.mData; 

  for (int j = 0; j < inNumberFrames*2; j++){ 

     sampleinp = *musicPlaybackState->samplePtr++; 

     outSample[j] =  b0a0 * sampleinp + 
     b1a0 * x1 + 
     b2a0 * x2 - 
     a1a0 * y1 - 
     a2a0 * y2; 


     x2=x1; 
     x1=sampleinp; 

     y2=y1; 
     y1=outSample[j]; 

  }} 





return noErr; 
}
```

Having Clicks/pop problems. Someone PLEASE HELP... I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is in Xcode using C in Objective-C. I tried making the Coeff Global and Static but no luck. The Audio file using is a .caf I tried .wav but still no good....

Thanks, sorry for the general cry for help. I'm new to this site.. I'm trying to add an Peak filter in my app but everytime I use a slider or just leave the gain at 1 I get pops and clicks. It seems as everthing is there and working properly as far as holding the previous samples etc. I also get some type of phase when changing the frequency or the bandwidth. I'm so confused been studying dsp for a few months now, I think it's something with Objective-C and a lil user error. It seem to go away when changing the sample to a SInt32 but the left channel disappears when changing freq.

Dsp.h

```
typedef struct { 

  void* audioData; 

   UInt32 audioDataByteCount; 

   SInt16 *samplePtr; 

} MusicPlaybackState;
```

Comment: I can't imagine why someone is voting to close this.

Comment: @Slomojo: I don't think the question should be closed, but it's not very well posed as it stands, and I can see why it might get close votes. @Cocell: you might want to improve the question to avoid further close votes - try giving more detail about the problem and what you have tried, and make it a single specific question rather than a general "cry for help".

Comment: @Paul R - I would agree that the question should be more effectively posed, but the completely silent vote to close is inappropriate.  It is 100% apparent that Cocell is a new user to SO and, simply wants to solve a thorny issue.  It's not possible for someone with less than 2k rep to vote for a close, so it's extremely disappointing when this happens. It's arbitrary, unhelpful and frankly rude, a comment requesting more information if it's required is all that is needed here, not a "GO AWAY, YOUR QUESTION IS UNWANTED" which is exactly what a close vote conveys.

Comment: @Slomojo: you're right, of course that a close vote should always have a comment explaining the reason, but unfortunately we do seem to get a lot of "drive-by" close votes with no comments.

Comment: @eryksun The Data Type is SInt16, Hope thats what you need. I haven't put a SineWave through yet for testing. I was testing with different Stereo Songs thinking the filter would work. This is driving me crazy. I've been creating filters using MATLab and then trying to implement them in my app but no luck even when having static coeff.

Comment: @Paul R - yes, it's pretty "says a bad word"-ty.

Comment: When Data Type is at Sint32 the loop is inNumberFrames without Multiply it by 2. The audio works but the filter doesn't, the L channel distorts when changing freq and gain. at Sint16, I multiply it by 2 else it would sound slugish. I haven't tried given each channel its own buffer or State Variables, maybe that could be the problem since I do get I believe a 180 phase when changing the frequency at Sint16. Or maybe when it's Sint32, the filter is only working on the right channel??? I think your on to sumtin eryksun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per hotpaw2's answer, here's the plot of your filter's response:

```
from pylab import *
import scipy.signal as signal

def biquad_peak(omega, gain_db, bandwidth):
    sn = sin(omega)
    cs = cos(omega)
    alpha = sn * sinh(log(2) / 2 * bandwidth * omega / sn)
    gain_sqrt = 10.0 ** (gain_db / 40.0)

    # feed-forward coefficients
    b0 = 1.0 + alpha * gain_sqrt
    b1 = -2.0 * cs
    b2 = 1.0 - alpha * gain_sqrt
    # feedback coefficients
    a0 = 1.0 + (alpha / gain_sqrt)
    a1 = -2.0 * cs
    a2 = 1.0 - (alpha / gain_sqrt)
    # normalize by a0
    B = array([b0, b1, b2]) / a0
    A = array([a0, a1, a2]) / a0
    return B, A

omega = 2 * pi * 800.0 / 44100.0
gain_db = 1.0
bandwidth = 2.0

B, A = biquad_peak(omega, gain_db, bandwidth)
w, H = signal.freqz(B, A)
f = w / pi * 22050.0
plot(f, abs(H), 'r')
gain = 10.0 ** (gain_db / 20.0)
print  "Gain:", gain
plot(f, gain*ones(len(f)), 'b--'); grid()
```

[image: biquad peak filter response]

The peak gain is set to 1.1220184543 (i.e. 1 dB). You can see how the filter causes most of the audible range to have a gain greater than 1.

Edit 2: 
If this is for an adjustable EQ, then it's up to the user to set the gain that avoids distortion. Plus I doubt the extreme problem you describe would be caused by a mild gain of 1 dB over a narrow band for a typical audio track. I think instead it's because your audio has interleaved stereo data. Each of these channels needs to be filtered separately. I've taken a crack at modifying your nested loop to accomplish this:

```
a0 = 1.0 + alpha / A; 
a1 = -2.0 * cs / a0;     
a2 = (1.0 - alpha / A) / a0; 
b0 = (1.0 + alpha * A) / a0; 
b1 = -2.0 * cs / a0; 
b2 = (1.0 - alpha * A) / a0;

double static x11, x12, x21, x22;
double static y11, y12, y21, y22;
double x0, y0;

for (int i = 0; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++) {  

    AudioBuffer buffer = ioData->mBuffers[i]; 
    AudioSampleType *outSample = buffer.mData; 

    for (int j = 0; j < inNumberFrames*2; j++) { 

        /* x0 is in the range of SInt16: -32768 to 32767 */

        x0 = *musicPlaybackState->samplePtr++;

        y0 = b0 * x0 + 
             b1 * x11 + 
             b2 * x12 - 
             a1 * y11 - 
             a2 * y12; 

        outSample[j] = fmax(fmin(y0, 32767.0), -32768.0); 

        x12 = x11; 
        x11 = x0;
        y12 = y11;
        y11 = y0
        j++;          

        x0 = *musicPlaybackState->samplePtr++;

        y0 =  b0 * x0 + 
              b1 * x21 + 
              b2 * x22 - 
              a1 * y21 - 
              a2 * y22; 

        outSample[j] = fmax(fmin(y0, 32767.0), -32768.0); 

        x22 = x21; 
        x21 = x0;          
        y22 = y21; 
        y21 = y0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that even if you guarantee that the gain is <= 1.0 at all frequencies, you may still get output peaks that are bigger than your input peaks.

Comment: So how would I boost a freq at 10000kHz for example peaking at 12dB without clicks and pops if your saying it has to be less than 1dB?

Comment: @eryksun No just using that for an example. Was just wondering though what if I wanted to boost 12dB @ a certain freq, whould that cause the same problem? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Wow that solved all the problems. I can't believe it was something so simple but hard. Just had to add the second channel in the loop and stay between -1.0-1.0. Thank you all, and thank you sooo much eryksun this was really killing me. Man I'm soo happy.

Comment: If anyone can answer this, not a big problem, when trying to boost or cut gain,dB which is 20*log10(A), the question is how can I get -12dB/12dB without clipping if I have to stay between -1.0-1.0 in magnitude? How do I figure out where it's flat?

Comment: @eryksun Yeah I already added the AGC, because I was still getting a little clipping..That was what I was going to do next (SInt32). So for my Input and coefficients I would change to SInt32 then take away inNumberFrames*2 to inNumberFrames for processing then Output back to SInt16, which is what the iPhones read. I tried that before and My left channel was missing so reworking it that way would reduce a lot of clipping I think.

Comment: Never mind the input Data Type last comment. Changing Coefficients data type wouldn't make that much of a difference.

Comment: @eryksun Everything is working. I had an if statement for the AGC but I like your method better. Now I can go past 1.0 without clipping. I think this is good reference for anybody doing any DSP with an iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch. Thanx again All. :)

Answer (score 2):

one important issue is that your filter state must be stored within the `refcon` state (at least, that is the obvious best place in typical cases).

without that, your filter is rebuilt and initialized at every invocation of the callback which means the state will not be preserved correctly and you'll have glitches at the boundaries of every callback other than the first.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using RBJ's biquad cookbook recipe.

A biquad peaking filter with an average gain of 1.0 has a gain above 1.0 at certain frequencies.  If you don't want clipping, you either have to use a gain of less than 1.0, or use an attenuator or AGC on the input so that the peak frequency boost never gets to a level that will clip.

It's a problem without an AGC, since some customers expect a peaking or bass boost filter to make things louder, and you have to attenuate the average level to actually lower to completely prevent clipping at the peaking frequency.

Comment: Ok I will try adding an AGC. So your basically saying the reason it's making the sounds is because the gain at different freq is more than 1.0 in Magnitude not dB as eryksun mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent answers that have already been given, I'll just add a general word of advice - you should factor out and decouple your filter routine from the callback (i.e. make it a separate function with no dependencies on your iOS code). That way you can put it in a test harness and more easily debug it (in a non-real-time context), separate from any iOS-specific issues that might complicate matters.

Comment: Thanks I do have it like that on my 2nd version and still same issue. I just put it in all together to make it easier to help.

Comment: @Cocell: OK - when you have the routine implemented separately write a test harness which can generate an input signal, e.g. sine wave at given amplitude and frequency, and then dump the output in a format that can be plotted - makes debugging etc much easier.